# Multiple apple products with 1 account

Tags: apple-id, game-center, clash-of-clans

I started an account on Game Center when I was the only one with an iPhone. When my oldest got an iPhone, he got his own log in account to games Center. When my youngest got an iPod touch, I logged him into my account so I could better monitor what was being played and downloaded. But now I have an iPad and want to play Clash of Clans with my kids. So the three of us play together on different devices. Oldest with his own account! Youngest and I are playing off the same games Center account from different devices.

Each time I log into the game, it asks me if I want to sinc it with my games Center (which would erase my game and load my youngest's onto my ipad) erasing my game. How do I get the games Center to leave this game alone on my ipad?

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible by opening the "Game Center" app on your youngest son's device and logging him into a third Apple account, or possibly just logging him out of Game Center. Depending on the game, if you are playing over wifi at the same time he may not need to be logged into the Game Center account for the others to see his activity.